# Can you update CSS from an API?

Tags: css, api

I want to create CSS for the body of my react app that updates based on information from an API. Is that possible? Can you use if/else conditions?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best methods is change class, not style.

For example:

```
if (true) {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.classList.toggle("mystyle"); 
    // or element.classList.add("mystyle"); ( but Toggle is better)
}
```

Reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a library like [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to conditionally render classes in React:

```
import classnames from 'classnames';   

// Individual class
<div className={
   classnames({ 'enabled': data.length })
}>


// Multiple classes
<div className={'first-class',
   classnames({ 'enabled': data.length })
}>
```

You could also use the ternary operator to conditionally render classes, which would look like this:

```
// Individual class
<div className={data.length ? 'enabled' : null}>


// Multiple classes
<div className={`first-class ${data.length ? 'enabled' : null}`}>
```